# My image is not displaying

Tags: html, css

I want a icon to display on the left side of my "Skriv ut" text but for some reason it's not displaying.

I want it like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <a href="javascript:window.print();" class="Print">Skriv ut</a>    
    </div>
```

css

```
.Print:link, .Print:visited {
    background: url(../img/Icon.png) 0 -320px no-repeat transparent;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 22px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3jof9ex/3/

Comment: Where does `-320px` come from? The `:link` and `:visited` pseudo-selectors are also unnecessary: http://jsfiddle.net/xgfb1ftr/

Comment: like this one http://jsfiddle.net/j3jof9ex/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes but it works now, I hope this is the way you wanted it.
Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3jof9ex/4/).

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <div class="print-icon"></div>
  <a href="http://www.google.nl" target="_blank" class="Print">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    Skriv ut
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.Print:link,
.Print:visited {
   float: left;
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   padding-bottom: 6px;
   padding-left: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.Print:link, .Print:visited {
    background: transparent url(http://placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat left center ;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Note: You can adjust the background doing this: `background: transparent url(http://placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat left -10px center 20px;`

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/j3jof9ex/7/)**